# Migrate a Current branch to Master branch without losing history or no failure - (hard merge)

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, git-rebase

I have a classic situation where we were all working on the *master* branch and somewhere between when we had to perform a parallel pipelining process we cut the branch off this master and created a new branch say feature , now this feature branch started to have commits from the entire people and no commit landed in master.

Now after almost 7 months we worked on feature branch and now we want to merge this to *master* without losing the history of *master* branch. We have almost 2000 commits in feature branch so *rebase* is just a dangerous operation.

Approach we are thinking:

- rename the branch feature to master and master to xxxxx ( but I don't know how to keep the history of master branch)
- Perform a hard merge by first make a MR against master branch and delete everything in master and then force merge feature to master.
- Just go for rebase (might be less painful but could be catastrophic when conflicts).

appreciate the steps to perform this accurately. We use `Gitlab`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no history *of* a branch.<sup>1</sup>  There is history *in* a branch, because a branch name identifies one particular commit, and that commit identifies one or more previous commits, each of which also identify still-earlier commits and so on.  We then say that these commits are *in* (contained within) that branch.  They may also be contained within other branches as well.

The *history* in a Git repository *is* the commits.  The commits *are* the history.  If you have the commits, you have the history.  They are the same thing, so there's no need to be concerned about separating them.  The tricky part here is that the *commits* are found by their hash IDs.  The hash IDs are big and ugly and impossible for humans to deal with correctly on any kind of long-term basis.  So we don't even try: we use *branch names* to find the *latest* commit, from which we find all the earlier commits.

What this means for you is that your simplest approach, of renaming `feature` to `master` (or `main` or whatever you like) after renaming whatever name(s) may be in the way first, is probably the way to go.  If, later, you wish to find a commit that can only be found by searching backwards from whatever used to be called `master`, when that is now called, say, `history-from-1927`,<sup>2</sup> you would run `git log history-from-1927` or `git log origin/history-from-1927` to find it.

A branch name—or a remote-tracking name like `origin/whatever`, which Git creates in clones so that the user of the clone<sup>3</sup> can see what the original repository could see—allows you, as the user of the clone, to find and see the commits without having to memorize their hash IDs.  (It also *protects* those commits from being *garbage collected*, which is a matter for a separate question.)

---

<sup>1</sup>This isn't entirely right, as Git keeps so-called *reflogs* for branch names and other references.  However, that's not what you mean.  Reflogs are also specific to one particular repository: this history is not transferred by cloning.

<sup>2</sup>Obviously 1927 is unrealistic; even 1972 would be before Git existed.  It's just meant to be whatever name you've used, without suggesting that you use *this* name, which is a terrible name.  Use a better one.

<sup>3</sup>The person who makes the gets his or her *own* branch names *in* that clone, to use as he/she/they see fit.  That's why their Git renames the *origin*-al (`origin`) branch names: if they want to create their own `main` and/or `feature` and/or whatever other names, they won't be affected by the names in the `origin` repository.  Instead, their `origin/*` names will be affected by those names.  That's why we have remote-tracking names: they *track* the *branch* names in the *remote* Git.  We run `git fetch` to obtain any new commits that they have, that we don't have yet; this updates our remote-tracking names to remember those new commits, just as *they* updated *their* **branch** names to remember those new commits.

Comment: Thank you for the long and clear answer , I agree to use the renaming approach. Do you by any chance have a set of steps that you would recommend me ?

Comment: On the server (if you have access to it) use `git branch -m` to rename the branches. On each clone, have each user use `git branch -m` to rename *their* branches, and run `git fetch --prune` to clean up their remote-tracking names. If you don't have direct access to the server, this is a bit more tricky: you want to make sure nobody is trying to run `git push` while you do your various steps and that's a lot easier if you *do* have access to the server (you just move the Git repository out of the way while you rename branches, then move it back when done).

Comment: So, if you *can't* log in to the server, e.g., if it's on GitHub or something: get everyone quiet for a while so that you can do your updates without interruption. Then, in a clone, run `git fetch` to make sure you're all up to date, then use `git push` carefully *from* the clone to create new branch names on the server, and delete old branch names on the server. Remember that `git push` has, on the client, the syntax: `git push <remote> <local-identifier>:<remote-name>`, so that you can do, e.g., `git push origin master:new-name`.

Comment: You can then follow this up with `git push origin :master` or `git push origin --delete master` to delete the *name* `master` on `origin`, now that `new-name` is also a name for those same commits. Then once the *name* `master` is gone on `origin` you can `git push should-be-master:master`, for instance. You can also `git push origin/should-be-master:refs/heads/master`. This is a little trickier: you're using the *full name* (`refs/heads/master`) to point out that this is to be a branch name. You need this when pushing from a hash ID or something else that's not a branch name, locally.